# Convert back to 2D numpy array from .jpg image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I saved an numpy array to an image as follows:

```
plt.imshow(xNext[0,:,:,0]) #xNext has shape (1,64,25,1)
print(xNext[0,:,:,0].shape) #outputs (64,25)
plt.savefig(os.path.join(root,filename)+'.png')
np.save(os.path.join(root,filename)+'.npy',xNext[0,:,:,0])
```

How can I obtain the same numpy array back from the .png saved image? Can you also please show me if I had saved as .jpg image?

I've tried the following and works with 3D array (v1) where resulting image close to the original numpy array produced image (original).

```
image = Image.open(imageFilename) #brings in as 3D array
box = (315,60,500,540)
image = image.crop(box)
image = image.resize((25,64)) #to correct to desired shape
arr = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.savefig('v1.png')
plt.close()
```

However, when I convert the 3D array to 2D array, the resulting image is different (v1b and v1c).

```
arr2 = arr[:,:,0]
plt.imshow(arr2)
plt.savefig('v1b.png')
plt.close()
arr3 = np.dot(arr[...,:3],[0.299,0.587,0.11])
plt.imshow(arr3)
plt.savefig('v1c.png')
plt.close()
```

How can I convert the 3D to 2D correctly? Thanks for your help.

original, v1 (saved from 3D array)

[image: original]
[image: v1]

v1b, v1c (saved from 2D arrays)

[image: v1b]
[image: v1c]

original (with original size)

[image]

Comment: `image = Image.open(imageFilename)` also produces a different result

Comment: Could you provide a link to the original data (xNext)?

Comment: .npy file with original data of xNext available at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KAfxGSruTgszMW3DuZ3uH7-UjZlx6Jec/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to save a numpy array as an image, your approach have a problem. The function `plt.savefig` saves an image of the plot, not the array. Also transforming an array into an image may carry some precision loss (when converting from `float64` or `float32` to `uint16`). That been said, I suggest you use **skimage** and **imageio**:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np

from skimage import img_as_uint

data = np.load('0058_00086_brown_2_recording1.wav.npy')
print("original", data.shape)

img = img_as_uint(data)
imageio.imwrite('image.png', img)
load = imageio.imread('image.png')

print("image", load.shape)
```

This script loads the data you provided and prints the shape for verification

```
data = np.load('0058_00086_brown_2_recording1.wav.npy')
print("original", data.shape)
```

then it transform the `data` to `uint`, saves the image as png and loads it:

```
img = img_as_uint(data)
imageio.imwrite('image.png', img)
load = imageio.imread('image.png')
```

the output of the script is:

```
original (64, 25)
image (64, 25)
```

i.e. the image is loaded with the same shape that data. Some notes:

- **image.png** is saved as a grayscale image
- To save to **.jpg** just change to `imageio.imwrite('image.jpg', img)`
- In the case of **.png** the absolute average distance from the original image was `3.890e-06` (this can be verified using `np.abs(img_as_float(load) - data).sum() / data.size`)

Information about [skimage](https://scikit-image.org/) and [imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) can be found in the respectives websites. More on saving numpy arrays as images can be found in the following answers: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696615/can-i-save-a-numpy-array-as-a-16-bit-image-using-normal-enthought-python/25814423#25814423), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102051/read-the-picture-as-a-grayscale-numpy-array-and-save-it-back) and [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929052/how-to-save-an-array-as-a-grayscale-image-with-matplotlib-numpy).

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks great. I'll test it out in the next couple of days and mark as answer and award bounty if it all works out which looks like it should. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

[link](http://prancer.physics.louisville.edu/astrowiki/index.php/Image_processing_with_Python_and_SciPy)

```
 from scipy.misc import imread
 image_data = imread('test.jpg').astype(np.float32)
```

This should give you the numpy array (I would suggest using imread from scipy)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work (I'm still checking). I had to use np.uint8 instead of np.float32 but you wouldn't have known that. Thanks again

Comment: This gets me to (64,25,3) but I need just (64,25). I tried using gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b but didn't seem to work.